# retrieve local file using path java 7

Tags: java, path, java-7, java.nio.file

how can you retrieve a local file using "java.nio.file.Paths" for java 7 or any other API . I have this line of code but it returns the wrong directory format.

```
public static InputStream readfile(String filename) throws FileNotFoundException
{
persistenceService = (PersistenceService) ServiceManager.lookup(PersistenceService.class.getCanonicalName());
URL url = Paths.get(filename).toUri().toURL();
FileContents fileContents = persistenceService.get(url);
```

Result when printing url is:

```
file:/C:/Users/username/Desktop/filedirectory/filename
```

Supposed to be:

```
file:C:/Users/username/Desktop/filedirectory/filename
```

How can I get rid of that first `/` or is this a wrong method? 
Copied the two URLs in a windows explorer, the first one opens a webpage and cannot display, the second one opens the file I need.

Comment: You say "Result is:"... is this when printing `url`? Why do you think the result is wrong, does `persistenceService.get(url)` throw an exception?

Comment: @Duncan Yes this is when printing url. persistenceService.get(url) throws java.io.FileNotFoundException

Comment: What type is `persistenceService` and what is the value of `filename`?

Comment: @Duncan I edited the question since i cannot put the code in the right format in comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get contents of a local file, you don't need to use PersistenceService, you can just use the `java.nio.file.Files` class:

```
Path path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(filename);
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(path, charset);
```

If you want to use javax.jnlp.PersistenceService, read the documentation on http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/javaws/jnlp/javax/jnlp/PersistenceService.html:

> An application is only allowed to access data stored with a URL that is based on its codebase. For example, given the codebase http://www.mysite.com/apps/App1/, the application would be allowed to access the data at the associated URLs:
>
> - `http://www.mysite.com/apps/App1/`
> - `http://www.mysite.com/apps/`
> - `http://www.mysite.com/`

So it seems URLs beginning with `file:` are not to be used.

Comment: My method needs to return an inputstream from the contents of the file. How can that be achieved using java.nio.file.Files

Comment: Use Files.newInputStream(Path, OpenOption ...). It's well described in the API reference, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html

Comment: Oh, and if you want to create a BufferedReader instance on top of that stream, you just use Files.newBufferedReader(Path, OpenOption ...).